# Outlook 2007 Html table td elements

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, rendering, outlook-2007

I try to make newsletter compatible with Outlook 2007, but Outlook rendering engine isn't very logical. Following code is not making borders as width of 1 pixel like in Firefox and other rendering engines, but it adds some extra space between some of these td-elements. Is there a workaround for this issue ?

```
<table>
<tr>

<td width="0" style="border-left: 1px solid #cdcdcd; border-bottom: 0px none; border-top: 0px none; margin: 0;" ></td>
<td width="0" style="border-left: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-bottom: 0px none; border-top: 0px none; margin: 0;" ></td>
<td width="0" style="border-left: 1px solid #adadad; border-bottom: 0px none; border-top: 0px none; margin: 0;" ></td>
<td width="0" style="border-left: 1px solid #949494; border-bottom: 0px none; border-top: 0px none; margin: 0;" ></td>

<td width="100%" bgcolor="white">
content here
</td>

<td width="0" style="border-right: 1px solid #949494; border-bottom: 0px none; border-top: 0px none; margin: 0;" ></td>
<td width="0" style="border-right: 1px solid #adadad; border-bottom: 0px none; border-top: 0px none; margin: 0;" ></td>
<td width="0" style="border-right: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-bottom: 0px none; border-top: 0px none; margin: 0;" ></td>
<td width="0" style="border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd; border-bottom: 0px none; border-top: 0px none; margin: 0;" ></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also see the links in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868073/is-it-true-that-newsletters-in-html-should-have-a-table-based-layouts/868134#868134

Comment: Here is how it looks in Outlook 2007 >>

http://i44.tinypic.com/8zmxhj.jpg

Answer (score 3):

I just set border-collapse:"collapse", cellspacing="0", cellpadding = "0" with my Outlook 2007 and it helped.

Comment: Can you tell me to which elemnts you put those values, beause Im stil getting errors with those attributes...

Comment: This answer agrees with [this blog-entry](http://www.ianhoar.com/2008/04/29/outlook-2007-borders-and-1px-padding-on-table-cells/), but adding `border/cellpadding/cellspacing=0` attributes and `border-collapse:collapse` on the table (and td, per that article) did not solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

`<table cellspacing = "0">` will solve your problem if I understand it correctly

Comment: No, because it looks like random spaces between td-elements

Answer (score 2):

have you tried setting "border-collapse: collapse" on the table?

A very usefull guide to show which CSS properties are supported in Outlook 07/03: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2533/a-guide-to-css-support-in-emai-2/#pc

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do your newsletter with Word 2007, saving it as `HTML` and then tweaking it (triming unnecesary things) for the rest of the email clients.

Outlook (<2007) by default uses Trident, IE's engine for incoming mail, and Word HTML rendering engine for outgoing mail... [Until Office 2007, and people hate it.](http://blogs.zdnet.com/microsoft/?p=229)

Now, [it uses Word 2007's rendering](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2393/microsoft-takes-email-design-b/), wich [is rather lacking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx). [On microsoft's page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx) you can see the attributes you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before. To make it display correctly in Outlook, you have to have it like:

```
<td style="border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;">
```

to make the borders show up.

It's a bit weird, but that's Microsoft for you.