# Is there a program to preview an HTML ad in outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook-2007

So like many online companies, we send e-mail advertisements. Outlook 2007 has some quirky HTML rules so things that look fine in any browser, when sent to Outlook 2007, look horrific.

Is there a program where I can preview what the HTML would look like in Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone ;-) What I do is try sending the email to me (alone) and then see how it comes out. AFAIK there are no software which can show you the preview ;-)

Edit: [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868132/outlook-2007-html-table-td-elements) which some useful which you use while sending HTML emails.

Comment: :)

But say I have some HTML a stylesheet, and pictures and tables and <div>s and words ... how can I send that to myself?

Comment: You can open the HTML file in IE... then File -> Send -> Page by Email... Then the page pens in outlook.. But What you see is not what you get ;-) so send the email to your self and see how it renders.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue because of the switch from IE to Word as the rendering engine in Outlook 2007. 
So I have been using Word 2007 to preview the HTML file to see how it looks, before sending it to Outlook. It has so far worked fine in my case. Try it and let us know if it works for all your cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hello sendning Mass Mails throw Outlook isnt a good idea.
There are Many Opensource Massmailer Try http://sourceforge.net/projects/tellmatic/

And  a preview option isnt aviable for html files nor other things in outlook no matter which version 2003 or 2007 or 2010.

Comment: i'm excited, i am going to give it a try

Comment: dont you find the anser usefull? if you find usefull please vote :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ive had exactly this same issue.

What i had to do is download outlook 2007 to sort this out, and then created a program to send myself emails to test.

Alternatively you can use this site to send emails to any email address:
http://ctrlq.org/html-mail/

Old thread i know, but i think my answer can help anyone that stumbles across this question much as i did.