# remove space around html email in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have what looks like a 20px margin or padding in a html email in outlook and I can't get rid of it. 
The same thing is happening in apple mail client except only on the top not on the left. 
I have set the body margin and padding to be 0. Anyone got any ideas to fix this.

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="489" width="638" align="left"></table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the table itself has a margin and/or padding around it?

Comment: Tried adding margin and padding 0 to the table but still getting that 20px around the entire html email

Answer (score 0):

Just like browsers, email clients have default styling for certain elements and default structuring.  You may have a `<p>` that is put in there by default which might have `margin` pre-applied to it.  Try adding a line of css above your `<body>`

```
p { margin: 0; }
```

I haven't tested this, but it seems like it might be possible.

Also, if that doesn't work, here's an [answer to the same ? on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5885885/1408356) that suggests this can't be overcome. :\